# httpd local virtualhost example

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

**-- Original post ---**

I'd like to setup a dev env to play with some apache features. I'm running httpd on fedora.

I added to hosts local redirects

```
# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 example1.com
127.0.0.1 example2.com

# cmkdir /var/www/example1;      echo "Hello from /var/www/example1/index.html" > /var/www/example1/index.html
# cmkdir /var/www/example2;      echo "Hello from /var/www/example2/index.html" > /var/www/example2/index.html
# cmkdir /var/www/example2/sub ; echo "Hello from /var/www/example2/sub/index.html" > /var/www/example2/sub/index.html

# cvi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var//www/html"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/example1"
    ServerName example1.com

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/example2"
    ServerName example2.com

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/example2/sub"
    ServerName sub.example2.com
    ServerPath "/sub/"
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule "^(/sub/.*)" "/var/www/example2$1"

</VirtualHost>

# capachectl -t ; apachectl restart

# curl localhost
Hello from /var/www/html/index.html
# curl example1.com
Hello from /var/www/example1/index.html
# curl example2.com
Hello from /var/www/example2/index.html
# curl sub.example2.com
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
... ( lots of stuff different from the one i echoed) ...
```

If I do the same thing in local firefox - localhost works as expected, example1.com works as expected, but sub.example2.com redirects me to example2.com.

Can you please help me to figure out how to configure a local sub-domain? What is missing? Based on https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html I believe what I did is correct.

**-- Edit / Update ---**

If I follow the advice below from Newbie and change only the rewrite rule, without making any other changes from the setup above:

```
    <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/example2/sub"
        ServerName sub.example2.com
        ServerPath "/sub/"
#        RewriteEngine On
#        RewriteRule "^(/sub/.*)" "/var/www/example2$1"

    </VirtualHost>
```

I get :

```
# curl sub.example2.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: sub.example2.com
```

If I

```
# cat /etc/hosts | grep sub
127.0.0.1 example2.com sub.example2.com
```

It works as expected

```
#curl example2.com
Hello from /var/www/example2/index.html
# curl sub.example2.com
Hello from /var/www/example2/sub/index.html
```

Still this seems to be strange setup. I don't want to create /etc/hosts record for each sub-domain... Shouldn't it be possible to handle this situation only via the httpd VirtualHost setting, without changing the DNS settings locally or even worse - adding C records in the DNS of a domain(if not localhost)?  Any hint what I'm doing wrong? How can I get sub.example1.com to work without modifying the dns settings?

Regards,
Pavel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found out the answer to my question ...

** How to run locally sub-domains?**

/etc/hosts does not support wild cards(*.example2.com) and one needs to setup a local dns proxy server like dnsmasq for example. Otherwise for dev purposes you have to list (and then maintain :/ ) the sub-domains one-by-one in the /etc/hosts for local dev purposes.

**How to run the sub-domains via official DNS records for domain ?**

Seems laziest approach is to setup DNS settings having:

```
example2.com     A      the-server-IP
example2.com     MX 0   example2.com    
*.example2.com   CNAME  example2.com
```

Looking forward to your comments, if there is smarter approach. 
If you agree this is the way to go - please accept the answer, so other members know it is the way to go.

Regards, Pavel

Answer (score 0):

Remove the rewrite rule, it is used for redirecting so you have a loop.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80> DocumentRoot "/var/www/example2/sub" ServerName sub.example2.com ServerPath "/sub/"
```

Comment: Rewrite will redirect you for example from domain 1 to domain 2 it is used when you want to hide something from the user or to shorten the link ect. In your case by entering sub.example2 the apace was getting command to redirect request to example2.

Comment: Hello, 
thank you for your proposal. I tried commenting out RewriteEngine On and the RewriteRule, but it did not lead to the expected result...

# curl example2.com
Hello from /var/www/example2/index.html
# curl sub.example2.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: sub.example2.com

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if you run into problems.This dns would be able to work with your regular browsing since for all names it can't resolve it would check with googles dns and save it into its file.

```
    install bind
apt-get install bind9 -y

cd /etc/bind

vim named.conf.options

And uncomment forwarders and two rows bellow and instead of 0.0.0.0 enter google's dns IP (8.8.8.8).

service bind9 restart

vim named.conf.options

zone "YOURDOMAIN NAME" {
        type master;
        file "db.site.com";
        notify yes;
        };

cp db.local /var/cache/bind/db.site.com
cd /var/cache/bind/
vim db.site.com

$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     admin. admin.itlink.edu. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
        IN NS ns.YOURDOMAINNAMEHERE.
        IN      A       192.168.1.10 replace this with the IP of your PC that has apache installed
ns      A       192.168.1.10 replace this with the IP of your PC that has apache installed
www     A       192.168.1.10 replace this with the IP of your PC that has 



service bind9 restart
```